# Webtoon or manga has the main character traveling to multiple worlds to prevent isekai’d characters from ruining the original plot

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

I’m trying to find a story where the main character is transported to multiple worlds and each time they are expected to prevent an isekai’d character from ruining the original plot. I can’t remember if the main character is physically transported but I think they work for some kind of agency or god.

Comment: *The Executioner and Her Way of Life (Shokei Shoujo no Ikirumichi)* has an OP main character killing isekai arrivals.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And was the main character male or female?